# code not reached after for loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

In this function, right after the first for loop, code isn't being reached. The `alert("can't get here");` isn't working. Am I missing some obvious JavaScript caveat here?
The rest of the code can be found here: http://jsbin.com/tiweniludoqe/7/edit
Any help is much appreciated.

```
function checkForWin(){

    var winCondition = 0;

    //check for horizontal wins
    for(i = 0; i < board[i].length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            winCondition += board[i][j];
            if(winCondition === board[i].length) {
                alert("win detected horizontal");
            }
        }
        winCondition = 0;
    }
    alert("can't get here");

    //check for vertical wins
    for(i = 0; i < board[i].length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            winCondition += board[j][i];
            alert("winCondition: " + winCondition);
            if(winCondition === board[i].length) {
                alert("win detected horizontal");
            }
        }
    }

    //if diagonal / is 3 or -3 win
    //if diagonal \ is 3 or -3 win
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? Edit: There is an uncaught error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: well your first loop condition should be `board.length` instead of `board[i].length`

Comment: Isn't board[i] an array as well though? That is, an array inside an array.

Comment: Declare `i` and `j` with `var` and use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code is falling into an infinite loop by checking for board[i].length in the first *for* loop.

Try this:

```
function checkForWin(){

    var winCondition = 0;

    //check for horizontal wins
    for(i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { //HERE WE CHECK FOR board.length INSTEAD OF board[i].length
        for(j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            winCondition += board[i][j];
            if(winCondition === board[i].length) {
                alert("win detected horizontal");
            }
        }
        winCondition = 0;
    }
    alert("can't get here");

    //check for vertical wins
    for(i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { //HERE YOU HAD THE SAME PROBLEM
        for(j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            winCondition += board[j][i];
            alert("winCondition: " + winCondition);
            if(winCondition === board[i].length) {
                alert("win detected horizontal");
            }
        }
    }

    //if diagonal / is 3 or -3 win
    //if diagonal \ is 3 or -3 win
}
```

Final recomendation... When iterating with *for* loops try to user the *var* for the iterating variable, like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < board.length; i++)
```

Instead of:

```
for(i=0; i < board.length; i++)
```

By doing this you are avoiding to populate the global scope with those variables (in the case above *i*).